# Make controller can access from sub directory in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, directory

i know this question maybe has been to much to ask "[one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098362/codeigniter-making-sub-directory-controllers-work)".
I already try it,but it failed.

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And this my routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['na'] = 'na/na_contoller/index';
$route['nt'] = 'nt/nt_contoller/index';
$route['nul']= 'nul/nul_controller/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

This is my tree folder:

```
Mygroupfolder (personal)
-myapp (webadmin)
  |
  -controller
   -na(folder)
    |
     -Na_controller.php
   -nt
    ...
   -nul
```

and this Na_controller.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class na_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Construct our parent class
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('na_askes');
    }
}
```

but when i try access the url it doesn't work:

```
http://localhost/personal/webadmin/na/
```

> Object is not found
>   404

Thank you

Comment: in your .htaccess add this line `RewriteBase /personal/webadmin`

Comment: `object not found` i already add it ,nothing happen @KamranAdil

Comment: make sure `mod_rewrite` is enable in apache config and your folder name is myapp or webadmin ?

Comment: my app folder is webadmin, myapp is just defined my webadmin name in tree view. ok i'll try @KamranAdil

Comment: i already enable mod_rewrite by following this tutorial [link](http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/) but still the same i found `object not found`. am i wrong with this uri `http://localhost/personal/webadmin/na` @KamranAdil