# How to call controller from sub-sirectory Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

There is sub-directory `sub` in `controllers` directory with controller `Lang`:

```
/controllers/crm/languages/lang.php
```

When I try to call this controller from URL I get 404 error:

My routing is:

```
`$route["crm/languages"] = "crm/languages/lang/index";`
```

Comment: You might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098362/codeigniter-making-sub-directory-controllers-work .. Perhaps this is a similar thread

Answer (score 0):

use CodeIgniter HMVC Modules: https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-hmvc-modules