# how to access controller only with folder name using route

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to access controller only with folder name, folder exist in controller.
Folder name is admin inside controller folder. Controller is dashboard(php file) inside admin folder.

```
$route['admin/(:any)']  = 'admin/dashboard';
```

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to access dashboard(php file) using: http://Website/admin. But not working.I thnik, I have issue with above route line.
[image]

**Working route**

```
$route['(:any)'] = "admin/dashboard";
```

Using `$route['(:any)']` page can access with: http://Website/any-string-or-letter. But how to access only with: http://Website/admin.

Comment: mod_rewrite is you buddy... look into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter making sub-directory controllers work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098362/codeigniter-making-sub-directory-controllers-work)

Comment: @Vickel, no its different thing

Comment: @jorge Campos, I have updated my question with htaccess file.

Comment: So what is the problem, just getting a 404 error?

Comment: @Brian Gottier, yes, just getting a 404 error

Comment: @BilluG You can directly access that controller, The only thing you need to do is to include that folder name in your URL and remove the routing code you wrote in routes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to do this:

1. Create a folder inside controllers folder  `application/controllers/admin`
2. Create a controller inside your folder. For Example: `application/controllers/admin/dashboard`

Dashboard.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     */


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('my-view');
        //$this->load->view('admin/my-view'); //If you are saving the views in a sub directory under views/admin/my-view.php
    }

}
```

Create a `my-view.php` under `application/controllers/views/my-view.php`

```
<h5>MY VIEW FILE CONTENT</h5>
```

Access this controller like this: If you are on localhost then it will be like: `http://localhost/my-project/admin/dashboard/index`

- *No need to write any routes for this.
- *Check carefully your `.htaccess` file and [naming conventions for CodeIgniter 3](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html).

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my-project
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /my-project/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

- *update your project folder name.

routes.php

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
```

*Please try to remove/comment all other routes except this one to avoid the conflicts

Comment: how to call view, where you have commented line "Index Page for this controller" in Dashboard.php.

Comment: How to access controller using url(http://localhost/my-project/admin) instead of complete url(http://localhost/my-project/admin/dashboard/index) ?

Comment: create a view file under `application/views/my-view.php` and call using this function `$this->load->view('my-view');`

Comment: yes I have my view file view folder and call in Dashboard.php file. But Dashboard.php file showing error, can you please update Dashboard.php file with call view.

Comment: Working url :http://localhost/my-project/admin/dashboard/index, but short url is not working: localhost/my-project/admin.

Comment: Can you please update your code with `view` , `controller` and also how are you accessing it on your local server url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155373/discussion-between-harish-and-billu-g).

Comment: waiting in chat

Comment: @BilluG I have updated the script with updated code (Y)

Comment: @BilluG, Have you checked the updated script, we have resolved your question in chat discussion, Please you can make it as accepted answer.

Comment: can we restrict user to access controller using url (localhost/my-project/admin) only. Currently, controller can be accessed by both short and actual (full path or url).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are probably having right now is that CodeIgniter is expecting something in the place of (:any), so when you try to go to /admin it fails because there is no Admin.php controller, and you lacked the second URI segment. Try this:

```
$route['admin/(.+)'] = function ($x = NULL)
{
    return 'admin/dashboard';
};
```

Probably another thing to consider is what the CI user guide says about controllers in sub-directories, and that you may have a default controller:

> Each of your sub-directories may contain a default controller which will be called if the URL contains only the sub-directory. Simply put a controller in there that matches the name of your ‘default_controller’ as specified in your application/config/routes.php file.

Link to that section: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories

What that means is that if you look in config/routes.php, if your default_controller is "welcome", then you can also have a controller named application/controllers/admin/Welcome.php , and requests routed to /admin would go there if there was no other matching controller.

I don't think any of this is ideal. If it were me, I'd figure something else out in the way of app organization.